# Uniform probability density function

Tags: statistics, functions

If I have uniform probability density function:
$\pi(r)=1 \space \forall r\in [0,1] \space and \space 0 \space \forall r \notin [0,1]$
I just don't get it. If I integrate function f(x) from 0 to 0,5 and then from 0 to 0,7 how I get from both integrates 1 like $\pi(r)$ shows? That can't be true unless f(x) is zero between 0,5 and 1.

edit:
I'm thinking that $\pi (r)$ is a new (density)function which comes from integrated f(r). And that's probably wrong thinking because: $\pi (r)$ is always 1 on every X from 0 to 1 and if I integrate f(r) i.e from 0 to 0,5 and from 0 to 0,7 I won't get same result which should be 1..
I know this is a confusing question..

Comment: What is f(x)? You defined $\pi(r)$.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: @user77434: if you are the same person that wrote this question, you can merge your accounts as described on [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 3):

I believe here there is a misunderstanding.

> [From Wikipedia ...] "*probability distribution function*" may be used
>   when the **probability distribution** is defined as a function over
>   general sets of values, or it may refer to the **cumulative distribution
>   function** [...]

So here $\pi(r)$ is the **probability distribution** and not the **cumulative distribution function**. Therefore it is **not** the integration from $0$ to $r$ of a $f(r)$.

Now, if you'd like to calculate the **cumulative distribution function** $\Pi(r)$, by integrating from $-\infty$ and $r$ your $\pi(r)$, you get:

$$
\Pi(r) = \int_{-\infty}^r\!\pi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^r\!\pi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    0 & \quad r<0\\
    r & \quad 0\le r<1\\
    1 & \quad r\ge 1
  \end{array} \right.
$$